# liquid variables stop working when layout is defined

Tags: html, jekyll, github-pages, liquid, jekyll-theme

Big thanks to anyone who looks at this! I think the question is straightforward. It is only long because I wanted to be very thorough/ well-documented. I have taken the following example code from the [jekyll documentation](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/front-matter/) and edited it only so that I can find it with a permalink:

```
---
food: Pizza
permalink: "/pizza"
---

<h1>{{ page.food }}</h1>
```

When I run `jekyll serve`, the variable is outputted as it should be, but it has no layout. When I try to add a layout that I wrote to the page, the variable no longer outputs, as seen [here](https://cao826.github.io/pizza1).

Ultimately, I want to write an archive page that loops through categories, [exactly like this code in the documentation](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/posts/):

```
{% for category in site.categories %}
  <h3>{{ category[0] }}</h3>
  <ul>
    {% for post in category[1] %}
      <li><a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

But, because the liquid variables are not working, I cannot make the archive without either putting in in the `_layouts` directory or manually copy-pasting my layout to the archive page.

Sorry if I'm coming across as a jekyll newbie (I am) or if the answer is in the docs somewhere and I could not find it, but here are my questions:

1. Why is this behavior happening? Is it something about how jekyll works or is it my layout that is causing this?
2. What would be the best practice for writing the archive/ correcting this error?

The github repository for this entire project is [here](https://github.com/cao826/cao826.github.io)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are using the wrong liquid tag for trying to get the content. When injecting the page content, use `{{ content }}` not `{{ page.content }}`. You can see an example in [the docs](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/layouts/#usage).

Looking at your includes for `post_body.html` and `body.html`, you just need to fix the above and it should work.